# Virtual memory management on windows 7

Tags: performance, windows-7, virtual-memory

I found this article on technet regarding this topic:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff382717.aspx

Does microsoft have some benchmarks for various manual page file configurations?

Somebody told me that it is a good idea to create an extra partition on the drive with the OS with say 4.5 Gig and move the pagefile to this partition while disableing the first partition with the OS. Additionally it was suggested to manually set the page file size to limit 2 / 2 Gig.

In my eyes this makes no sense. Could someone comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer will satisfy you, but I've seen an opinion, that if you place your page file on ext[2-4] file system (you need drivers to do this on Windows, of course), system performance will increase.

However, I unfortunately can't recall where I've seen this (it was somehow connected with writing file system drivers using Installable FIle System API).

Comment: Thank you - but this doesn't answer my question.